# Can't Install Helm on GKE Cluster

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud, kubernetes-helm

I'm having trouble in installing Helm to one of my GKE cluster through gcloud shell.

When I run: `helm install --name mongo-rs-mongodb-replicaset -f 3-values.yaml stable/mongodb-replicaset --debug` This is what I get:

```
[debug] Created tunnel using local port: '39387'

[debug] SERVER: "127.0.0.1:39387"

[debug] Original chart version: ""
[debug] Fetched stable/mongodb-replicaset to /home/idan/.helm/cache/archive/mongodb-replicaset-3.9.6.tgz

[debug] CHART PATH: /home/idan/.helm/cache/archive/mongodb-replicaset-3.9.6.tgz

Error: the server has asked for the client to provide credentials
```

My service account is set properly:

```
kubectl describe serviceaccount tiller --namespace kube-system

Name:                tiller
Namespace:           kube-system
Labels:              <none>
Annotations:         <none>
Image pull secrets:  <none>
Mountable secrets:   tiller-token-vbrrn
Tokens:              tiller-token-vbrrn
Events:              <none>


kubectl describe clusterrolebinding tiller

Name:         tiller
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
Role:
  Kind:  ClusterRole
  Name:  cluster-admin
Subjects:
  Kind            Name    Namespace
  ----            ----    ---------
  ServiceAccount  tiller  kube-system
```

I'm owner of my project's IAM, and I'm not sure which credentials should I provide - I have never seen it in the past. Tried to initialize it with `helm --upgrade` too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After every solution I found didn't work, I tried re-creating my cluster and running the same commands and it has simply worked...

Answer (score 1):

Did you setup [rbac](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/docs/rbac.md#tiller-and-role-based-access-control)?
If not, set it up and run `helm init --service-account tiller --upgrade` it should fix your problem.

Comment: Tnxs, I tried it and it didn't work - anyway I found a solution, will share it as an answer